# WiFi Problem for Atheros Based Card in Toshiba

Tags: wireless, atheros, ath9k

My laptop is Toshiba C50-A628. The WIFI card in the laptop is Qualcomm Atheros ath9k. I am unable to turn on and see wifi networks through the laptop.

Comment: please run that script https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/669014 and post the output here

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the wireless hardware switch is turned off( assuming it has one) and turn it on. It’s usually located near the wireless indicator light.

Comment: You could do a search on the model to see if it even has a hardware switch